# Concatenate files placing an empty line between them

Tags: files, cat, newlines

I have a bunch of files with the same extension (let's say .txt) and I would like to concatenate them. I am using `cat *.txt > concat.txt`, but I would like to add a new line between each file so to distinguish them in concat.txt.

Is it possible to do it with a single bash command rather than an implementation such as [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/518951/concatenate-the-content-of-files-from-various-directories-with-a-blank-line-in-b)?

Thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using GNU `sed`:

```
sed -s -e $'$a\\\n' ./*.txt >concat.out
```

This concatenates all data to `concat.out` while at the same time appending an empty line to the end of each file processed.

The `-s` option to GNU `sed` makes the `$` address match the last line in *each* file instead of, as usual, the last line of all data.  The `a` command appends one or several lines at the given location, and the data added is a newline. The newline is encoded as `$'\n'`, i.e. as a "C-string", which means we're using a shell that understands these (like `bash` or `zsh`).  This would otherwise have to be added as a literal newline:

```
sed -s -e '$a\
' ./*.txt >concat.out
```

Actually, `'$a\\'` and `'$a\ '` seems to work too, but I'm not entirely sure why.

This also work, if one thinks the `a` command is too bothersome to get right:

```
sed -s -e '${p;g;}' ./*.txt >concat.out
```

Any of these variation would insert an empty line at the end of the output of the last file too.  If this final newline is not wanted, deletede it by passing the overall result through `sed '$d'` before redirecting to your output file:

```
sed -s -e '${p;g;}' ./*.txt | sed -e '$d' >concat.out
```

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas You know, GNU software tries to be _so_ convenient that it's sometimes difficult to understand the magic that they implement...

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas.  `sed -s -e $'a\\\n'` adds an extra newline to every line of every file - not just the last line of each file. It is not equivalent to `sed -s -e '${p;g;}'`

Comment: @Kusalananda. `sed -s -e $'$a\n' ./*.txt >concat.out` results in an extra newline at the end of `concat.out`. The OP wanted a newline between each file only.

Comment: @fpmurphy, sorry, I meant `$'$a\\\n'`, the point being that `$'$a\n'` is `$a<newline>`, not `$a<backslash><newline>` like in the variant not using `$'...'`.

Comment: @fpmurphy I'm aware that they get an extra newline at the end, and I'm ignoring it as it's trivial to remove it. Hmmm... I might mention how to do that anyway... Stephane was referring to a previous edit of my text that did not have the `p;g;` variation.

Answer (score 14):

Not a single command, but a simple one-liner:

```
for f in *.txt; do cat -- "$f"; printf "\n"; done > newfile.txt
```

That will give this error:

```
cat: newfile.txt: input file is output file
```

But you can ignore it, at least on GNU/Linux systems. Stéphane Chazelas pointed out in the comments that apparently, on other systems this could result in an infinite loop instead, so to avoid it, try:

```
for f in *.txt; do 
    [[ "$f" = newfile.txt ]] || { cat -- "$f"; printf "\n"; }
done > newfile.txt
```

Or just don't add a `.txt` extension to the output file (it isn't needed and doesn't make any difference at all, anyway) so that it won't be included in the loop:

```
for f in *.txt; do cat -- "$f"; printf "\n"; done > newfile
```

Comment: Not all `cat` implementations will give you that *input file is output file*. Some others will happily run here potentially causing an infinite loop that fills up the filesystem.

Comment: Note that `[[ "$f" = "newfile.txt" ]]` is a kshism. POSIXly, you'd use `[ "$f" = newfile.txt ]`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas wait, what? That's a `cat` issue? I always thought it was the shell, not `cat`. Then why doesn't `cat file1 file2 > file1` complain? As for the quotes, thanks fixed. Having unquoted strings feels weird to me.

Comment: For `cat file > file`, I suppose your `cat` detects `file` is empty and does nothing instead of reporting an error. Solaris `cat` still reports an error there. Note how the error message starts with `cat:`. I can't see how the shell could detect the condition.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas looks like you're right, unsurprisingly enough. This will reproduce the error: `( echo foo> newfile.txt; cat newfile.txt;  ) > newfile.txt` while this does not `( cat newfile.txt ) > newfile.txt`. So my `cat` (GNU coreutils, 8.32) seems to detect that the file is empty and doesn't complain in the second one. TIL, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Using GNU `awk`:

```
gawk -v RS='^$' -v ORS= '{
    print sep $0; sep="\n";
}' ./file*.txt >single.file
```

see [Slurp-mode in awk?](/q/304457/72456)

prefix dot-slash in files name `./` is used to avoid problems with files named like `file=x.txt` for instance as `awk` do reading these kind of *strings* as a *variable* when these come after `awk` codes;

Another GNU `awk` approach would be:

```
gawk 'BEGINFILE{if (ARGIND>1) print ""};1' ./file*.txt >single.txt
```

which is better as it would add an empty line even if the last line doesn't end in a newline character and would avoid loading the whole files in memory.

---

there is also a `sed` alternative, but to remove very last `\n`ewline, you should add another pipe `sed ... |`  to remove that.

```
sed -s '$s/$/\n/' file*.txt >single.file
```

Answer (score 5):

`zsh` has a `P` glob qualifier to prefix each filename resulting from a glob with an arbitrary argument.

While it's typically used for things like `cmd *.txt(P[-i])` to prefix each filename with a given option, you could use here to insert any given file before each file. A temporary file containing an empty line could be done with `=(print)`, so you could do:

```
() { cat file*.txt(P[$1]); } =(print)
```

On Linux or Cygwin, you could also do:

```
cat file*.txt(P[/dev/stdin]) <<< ''
```

To add an empty line between non-empty files only:

```
awk 'NR > 1 && FNR == 1 {print ""}; {print}' ./file*.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps not exactly what you were looking for, but like Quasímodo suggested in a comment, GNU's `tail` can add the empty line, in addition to a header with the filename:

```
$ echo 'this is foo' > foo.txt 
$ echo 'this is bar' > bar.txt   
$ tail -n+1 foo.txt bar.txt 
==> foo.txt <==
this is foo

==> bar.txt <==
this is bar
```

The `-n+1` causes it to print the whole file; it means "print the tail starting from line 1."

If you want the header to be added even when there is only one file for consistency, you can use `-v`.

```
$ tail -n+1 foo.txt        
this is foo
$ tail -v -n+1 foo.txt 
==> foo.txt <==
this is foo
```

Answer (score 1):

This does not work in POSIX `/bin/sh`, but in `bash`:

```
cat file1 <(echo) file2 >concatenated
```

The `<(echo)` is replaced by a temporary named pipe that is connected to the output of the `echo` command, which generates a single newline.

Comment: ... but it will only work easily for two files, and the OP seems to have "a bunch" of them. Maybe you can expand the answer to show how to make this into a shell script accepting "an arbitrary" number of input files?

Answer (score 1):

An example using Perl.

```
$ perl -e 'while(<>){print}continue{print"\n" if eof}' *.txt > concat.txt
```

which can be simplified to

```
$ perl -ne 'print; print "\n" if eof' [abc].txt > concat.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

`awk 1 *.txt`

Per
https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Very-Simple.html

when the awk action is omitted, as it is here, the default action is to print (with a newline) all lines that match the pattern; `1` matches every input line (regardless of whether it was newline terminated or EOF).

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

Raku can take files off the command line into the `$*ARGFILES` dynamic variable. The key here is to remember to convert to individual `$fh` filehandles using the `.handles` routine. Then simply pad the output as desired:

```
~$ raku -e 'for $*ARGFILES.handles -> $fh { put $fh, "\n", $fh.lines.join("\n"), "\n" };' file?
fileA
>TCONS_00000867
>TCONS_00001442
>TCONS_00001447
>TCONS_00001528
>TCONS_00001529
>TCONS_00001668
>TCONS_00001921
>TCONS_00001922

fileB
>TCONS_00001528
>TCONS_00001529
>TCONS_00001668
>TCONS_00001921
>TCONS_00001922
>TCONS_00001924

fileC
>TCONS_00001529
>TCONS_00001668
>TCONS_00001921
>TCONS_00001922
>TCONS_00001924
>TCONS_00001956
>TCONS_00002048

fileD
>TCONS_00001922
>TCONS_00001924
>TCONS_00001956
>TCONS_00002048
```

Sample Input: from [HERE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/768773/227738)

Sample Output: as above (each file padded with `$fh` filename before and a `\n` newline after).

---

*NOTE: Raku has a similar `next-handle` method with an `:on-switch` named-argument (see second link below for example usage), but above seems simplest.*

https://docs.raku.org/type/IO/ArgFiles#$*ARGFILES
https://docs.raku.org/type/IO/CatHandle#class_IO::CatHandle
https://raku.org