# Find a list of files and echo the file name and cat the file contents

Tags: cat

I want to print the filenames and contents for each file in order. I tried this `ls -1 after* | (echo;cat)` - This only lists the files, does not cat the contents of the files.
I also tried
`ls -1 after* | (echo; xargs cat)` - This only cats the contents, does not echo their paths. I would like to see something like

```
filename1
filename1_contents
filename2
filename2_contents
```

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/628692

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such option to `cat`. In bash shell:

```
for file in after*; do echo "$file"; cat "$file"; done
```

The file names will be sorted by default. See `man bash` for more on `for` loops.